# Can you develop Android programs on an Android device of Android tablet

Tags: android

I bought an Archos Android tablet and was wondering if it possible to develop Android applications on an Android device ( such as a table ) ?

At the moment I use Eclipse on a Windows PC.

Comment: You want to develop Android applications on an Android device itself? I don't think that's possible..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Standard Android development requires build tools (e.g., Java compilers) that do not run on Android, nor are likely to run on Android any time very soon.

[SL4A](http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/) allows you to write scripts in various languages, and has some ability for those scripts to have simple UIs and be distributed as APKs.

It is possible to modify a [PhoneGap](http://www.phonegap.com/) application to allow you to edit the HTML/CSS/Javascript content on a device and load up that content. However, it does not do this "out of the box", and you would still need the build tools (or access to build.phonegap.com) in order to create APK files.

There are probably other solutions in this general area as well. All are "non-traditional" ways of programming for Android, meaning they are on the fringes of mainstream Android development. Since you did not specify what your objectives are, it is unclear whether these sorts of solutions are meaningful to you or not.

Comment: While this answer was fine in it's time, it's no longer comprehensively accurate as sufficient tools to do normal development have now been ported to run on Android - see for example Enter_the_computer's answer of the following year.

Answer (score 11):

I've been looking for something like this to 
Her's what I found:

[AIDE](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aide.ui&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5haWRlLnVpIl0.)

[Droid Develop](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.assoft.DroidDevelop&feature=also_installed#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEwNCwiY29tLmFzc29mdC5Ecm9pZERldmVsb3AiXQ..)

I think there's also a touch keyboard, specifically for programming.
Aide I deffenetly like its good, haven't done a lot with it thou'. 
Droid Develop I found today, but it has a couple of addons, some free, some not.

Comment: I found AIDE while googling the OP's question myself. As this post was way back in 2012 I don't what it was like back then but AIDE is looking pretty good in 2014. It has RUN and COMPILE. YEAH!!

Answer (score -3):

I've researched this abit probably the closest you would get is to have windows 95 running on your tablet.. currently attempts of getting windows 95 to run results in it not being able install external software, you would have to usual a virtual drive to set it up first on your computer and use that iso for your purposes.

Also windows 95 does not support dual core.

The probably of you getting to work is very low.. and for you to run the emulator is even lower...

And even if it did run you wont have internet access or many other vital components.

Comment: Windows 95! Are you serious? You don't explain why this is necessary.